# Randomly arrange $k$ elements 'a' and $n-k$ elements 'b' into groups of size $g\leq k$. What is the probability of getting a group with all 'a'?

Tags: probability

I have a set of $n$ elements, where $k$ are of type $a$ and $n-k$  are of type $b$. I want to randomly group all elements into groups of size $g \leq k$. I'm trying to compute the probability that at least one of the groups contains all $a$.

Example:

I have this set of $n=10$ elements, with $k=4$:

$S = \{a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b,b\}$

Then I randomly group all elements into groups of size $g=2$:

$G = \{(a,b), (b,b), (a,b), (a,b), (a, b)\}$

I would like to know the probability of getting at least one $(a,a) \in G$, if the grouping process is random.

I know that the number of groups of size $g$ is $nCg$ and the number of possible $(a,\dots, a)$ groups is $kCg$. But I'm not sure how to continue from here.

Comment: Does order within a pair matter, ie is $ba$ considered different from $ab$ ?

Comment: no the order does not matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example, possible arrangements are $\binom{10}4$

For all $a's$ to be separate, there are $7$ points available

$- b - b - b - b - b - b -$, thus $\binom74$ possible arrangements

Subtract to get the answer for this particular case, and proceed

---

The above took order within a pair to matter.
As stated by OP, order within a pair doesn't matter.

To *mismatch* the first $a, 6 b's$ are available from $9$, and after each mismatch, the figures will reduce.
We can easily compute P(no $a's$ together)  $=\frac69\frac57\frac45\frac33 = \frac{24}{63}= \frac8{21}$

Thus at least two $a's$ together $= \frac{13}{21}, \approx 0.62$

Comment: Why are you using $x \choose 4$ instead of $x \choose 2$?

Comment: I am attempting to place $a's$ so that no two are together, and subtract from all possible placements of $a$. This is specific to the example you have given where there are $4$ $a's$

Comment: So that gives us the number of placements where two $a$'s occur together. I'm confused as to how to get the probability then. Is it $\frac{{10 \choose 4} - {7 \choose 4}}{{10 \choose 6} + {10 \choose 4}}$?

Comment: No, simply $\dfrac{\binom{10}4 - \binom74}{\binom{10}4}$

Comment: So that would be $p \approx 0.84$ and your reasoning makes sense. However, before posting the question I tried to simulate this scenario with code, by randomly shuffling, grouping and checking if I get a $(a,a)$ and the probability seems to approach $0.62$, instead of $0.84$. You can find the Python code here: https://pastebin.com/KUy5XYiy. I wonder why I get different probabilities.

Comment: Oh, the formula was where order within a pair  matters, the one where order doesn't matter  has been added, it matches your code results.

Comment: Nice that seems correct!. I have one last question if you don't mind. Let's say that now $n=12$ and $g=3$ with 4 $a$'s and 8 $b$'s. Then to mismatch the first $a$, we can either choose $ab$ or $bb$, and we can compute the probability of this happening. However, when we move on to the next group, it seems like we would have 4 options to consider: $ab$ (given we chose $ab$ before) or $bb$ (given $ab$) or $ab$ (given $bb$) or $bb$ (given $bb$). And If we increase the number of elements, this tree can expand much further. Is there an easier way to generalize this?

Comment: Difficult to generalize, but inclusion-exclusion, multinomial coefficient, and card distribution combinatorics could all help.